# How should I test a DynamoDB PutItem API made with AWS API Gateway in Postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have successfully built a DynamoDB PutItem API with the AWS API Gateway, and it's working as expected.

Currently I could only test the API in the default 'Test ⚡' option in API Gateway, but now I want to test it with Postman. Below are some details of the API:

Sample Invoke URL - https://abcxyz.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/put1

Here's a screenshot of the details I give to 'Test ⚡' option of API Gateway -

[image: Test option screenshot]

---

More clearly, I just need to provide the 'Path {cstid}' value, and a .json request body.

But somehow, I can't figure out how to make this work in Postman - where to put the invoke URL, where to add the Path {cstid}, and where to add the .json request body.

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the invoke URL in the URL bar. You can either add the query params manually in the URL bar or use the `params` tabs. Append the `cstId` as the path in the URL bar.
[image]

To enter the body go to the `body` tab and choose `raw` and select `JSON` as the type
[image]

Comment: Hi @Harry, Thanks for the answer! 

Please guide me through these questions - 
1) Why have you used the 'params' area in Postman? What exactly should I write there (in correspondence to Test screenshot attached in the question)? 
2) In the URL bar, you have written '/put1/{{cstid}}' : what's that? 
3) How would my complete URL look like if I want the value of 'cstid' to be 'CST100?' 

Thanks!

Comment: @kartik 2. I have used a `variable` `cstid` in the URL. It's a feature in Postman using which you can have a dynamic value. But, it's not needed for your use case. You can just replace it with the actual value `.../put1/CST100?....`

Comment: @kartik 1. `params` tab just simplifies adding query params to a URL. As mentioned you can manually add them directly In the URL using the syntax `.../path?key1=value&key2=value2&key3=value3...`. Using the `params` UI, you don't have to add the `?`, `&`, `=` characters

Comment: Thanks again @harry! I have understood your points clearly. But one last thing, according to the API I built, what values should be given in `params` area? I am giving the `cstid` in the URL, rest things like `age` , `name` & `mobile` through the Body. What should be given in the `?params` area? Thanks a lot!